# MUI generating component IDs and focusing elements with similar IDs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mui-x

I'm attempting to use `TreeView` from MUI-X within in my project, however when I try to expand a tree item it focuses a `TextField` in another, unrelated, component.

I noticed this happens when I refresh the page, and not when I link to the page using react-router.  In order to get a better idea of whats happening I print the focus events in the console using both the `onFocus` prop of the `TextField` and the `onNodeFocus` prop of the `TreeView` and this is what I find.

**When the page is refreshed and the `TreeView` is clicked, both `TreeView` and `TextField` are focused**
[Both events fired, similar ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf5yG.png)

**When navigating to the page via react-router and `TreeView` is clicked, only `TreeView` is focused and has the same id as when refreshed. `TextField` is not focused**
[Event with TreeView id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O920d.png)

**Directly clicking on `TextField` shows that after navigating to the page it has a different id than when the page is refreshed**
[Event with TextField id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBYA3.png)

From what I'm gathering, when I refresh the page the `TextField` component is given an id of `mui-1`, and when navigating to the page its given an id of `mui-428`.

When the `TextField` had the `mui-1` id it interferes with the `TreeView` id of `mui-1-1`, and whatever is used to find the element to focus is finding the similar `mui-1` in both components and focusing them both.

When I specifically give the `TextField` an id in the `id` prop of the component it fixes this behavior.

I'm just curious as to how/why does MUI generate element Ids, and why is it that if one element has an id which is a substring of another id, why are both acted on?

My current assumption is that since the `TreeView` is from the **Mui-X** package, it used its own id numbering and starts at `mui-1`, just as with the **Mui-Material** package.

I'd like to pose this question as a github issue, but the ids `mui-#` arent generated withing code sandbox for some reason.

Any insight into what might be happening would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little broad, and lacks any reproducible examples. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some guidance.